# Rating stars with 3.7, 4.269 rating (flutter)

Tags: flutter, widget, rating

I need widget to implement stars that can pe colored only for 70%, 87%

Answer (score 0):

You can pick one from these packeges https://pub.dev/packages?q=rating and add it to your project. My recommendation will be https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_star_rating that package.